# draw graph over video vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, video, draw

I have series of video files that i need to automatically draw some line over through to the en. The line varies, the values will be provided, is this possible in vb.net? what extra addin or controls do i need to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about actually modifying the video to include the lines or just floating a line over the video as it's playing in a window. I'd think that latter would be fairly straightforward, but the former would require a video editing library of some sort, definitely not something the vb (or C# for that matter) can do out of the box.

Comment: it is `actually modifying the video to include the lines`, how can do this?

Comment: Check out this thread for playing video with DirectShow. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/DirectShow_VB.aspx

For adding subtitles, I couldn't find anything right off, but I'd search the DirectShow API for anything having to do with SubTitle Filters.

Comment: I was going to suggestion checking out WPF and it's Media playback functionallity, but I don't believe you can actually alter the media with that, just overlay stuff on top of the playing media. Still, that might work for what you're doing.

Comment: it it possible then to do it as you said, and matbe recapture the application screen, saving it as a new video file.